# Starting to write QGIS Plugin?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, references

I'm taking my first steps in writing a plugin for QGIS by following this tutorial: http://www.qgisworkshop.org/html/workshop/plugins_tutorial.html

There is not even any functionality in this code, just setting up the plugin already fails.

I have already taken out a few errors that came with the limited imports that are now standard loaded with the plugin-builder plugin, but when i try to load this plugin it gives me the error :

> AttributeError: TRYOUT instance has no attribute 'handleMouseDown'

I found [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/90184/qgis-plugin-extending-plugin-stub-instance-has-no-attribute-error) bit of info, but i can't get that to work either.

Can anybody point me in the right direction of what i'm doing wrong?

```
#from PyQt4.QtCore import QSettings, QTranslator, qVersion, QCoreApplication
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from qgis.core import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
# Initialize Qt resources from file resources.py
import resources_rc
# Import the code for the dialog
from TOMODULE_dialog import TRYOUTDialog
import os.path

from qgis.gui import *


class TRYOUT:
    """QGIS Plugin Implementation."""
    def __init__(self, iface):
        """Constructor.
        :param iface: An interface instance that will be passed to this class
            which provides the hook by which you can manipulate the QGIS
            application at run time.
        :type iface: QgsInterface
        """
        # Save reference to the QGIS interface
        self.iface = iface

        # a reference to our map canvas
    self.canvas = self.iface.mapCanvas()
        # this QGIS tool emits as QgsPoint after each click on the map canvas
    self.clickTool = QgsMapToolEmitPoint(self.canvas)

        # initialize plugin directory
        self.plugin_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
        # initialize locale
        locale = QSettings().value('locale/userLocale')[0:2]
        locale_path = os.path.join(
            self.plugin_dir,
            'i18n',
            'TRYOUT_{}.qm'.format(locale))

        if os.path.exists(locale_path):
            self.translator = QTranslator()
            self.translator.load(locale_path)

            if qVersion() > '4.3.3':
                QCoreApplication.installTranslator(self.translator)

        # Create the dialog (after translation) and keep reference
        self.dlg = TRYOUTDialog()

        # Declare instance attributes
        self.actions = []
        self.menu = self.tr(u'&TRYOUTER')
        # TODO: We are going to let the user set this up in a future iteration
        self.toolbar = self.iface.addToolBar(u'TRYOUT')
        self.toolbar.setObjectName(u'TRYOUT')

    # noinspection PyMethodMayBeStatic
    def tr(self, message):
        """Get the translation for a string using Qt translation API.

        We implement this ourselves since we do not inherit QObject.

        :param message: String for translation.
        :type message: str, QString

        :returns: Translated version of message.
        :rtype: QString
        """
        # noinspection PyTypeChecker,PyArgumentList,PyCallByClass
        return QCoreApplication.translate('TRYOUT', message)


    def add_action(
        self,
        icon_path,
        text,
        callback,
        enabled_flag=True,
        add_to_menu=True,
        add_to_toolbar=True,
        status_tip=None,
        whats_this=None,
        parent=None):
        """Add a toolbar icon to the InaSAFE toolbar.

        :param icon_path: Path to the icon for this action. Can be a resource
            path (e.g. ':/plugins/foo/bar.png') or a normal file system path.
        :type icon_path: str

        :param text: Text that should be shown in menu items for this action.
        :type text: str

        :param callback: Function to be called when the action is triggered.
        :type callback: function

        :param enabled_flag: A flag indicating if the action should be enabled
            by default. Defaults to True.
        :type enabled_flag: bool

        :param add_to_menu: Flag indicating whether the action should also
            be added to the menu. Defaults to True.
        :type add_to_menu: bool

        :param add_to_toolbar: Flag indicating whether the action should also
            be added to the toolbar. Defaults to True.
        :type add_to_toolbar: bool

        :param status_tip: Optional text to show in a popup when mouse pointer
            hovers over the action.
        :type status_tip: str

        :param parent: Parent widget for the new action. Defaults None.
        :type parent: QWidget

        :param whats_this: Optional text to show in the status bar when the
            mouse pointer hovers over the action.

        :returns: The action that was created. Note that the action is also
            added to self.actions list.
        :rtype: QAction
        """

        icon = QIcon(icon_path)
        action = QAction(icon, text, parent)
        action.triggered.connect(callback)
        action.setEnabled(enabled_flag)

        if status_tip is not None:
            action.setStatusTip(status_tip)

        if whats_this is not None:
            action.setWhatsThis(whats_this)

        if add_to_toolbar:
            self.toolbar.addAction(action)

        if add_to_menu:
            self.iface.addPluginToMenu(
                self.menu,
                action)

        self.actions.append(action)

        return action

    def initGui(self):
        """Create the menu entries and toolbar icons inside the QGIS GUI."""

        icon_path = 'C:\Users\MAXBOOKPRO\.qgis2\python\plugins\DEVTEST\icon.png'
        self.add_action(
            icon_path,
            text=self.tr(u'Promote to Historical Feature'),
            callback=self.run,
            parent=self.iface.mainWindow())
    result = QObject.connect(self.clickTool, SIGNAL("canvasClicked(const QgsPoint &, Qt::MouseButton)"), self.handleMouseDown)
    QMessageBox.information(self.iface.mainWindow(),"Info", "connect = %s"%str(result))

    def handleMouseDown(self, point, button):
        QMessageBox(self.iface.mainWindow(),"Info", "X,Y = %s,%s" % (str(point.x()),str(point.y())) )   

    def unload(self):
        """Removes the plugin menu item and icon from QGIS GUI."""
        for action in self.actions:
            self.iface.removePluginMenu(
                self.tr(u'&TRYOUTER'),
                action)
            self.iface.removeToolBarIcon(action)


    def run(self):
        """Run method that performs all the real work"""
        # make our clickTool the tool that we'll use for now
    self.canvas.setMapTool(self.clickTool)
        # show the dialog
        self.dlg.show()
        # Run the dialog event loop
        result = self.dlg.exec_()
        # See if OK was pressed
        if result:
            # Do something useful here - delete the line containing pass and
            # substitute with your code.
            pass
```

Answer (score 5):

Note that you are using documentation from 2011. Since then QGIS has advanced to version 2.x and there was a Python API break between 1.7 and 2.0. You can find an up to date description of the plugin creation process as http://anitagraser.com/2014/04/26/getting-started-writing-qgis-2-x-plugins/

Answer (score 0):

You could also work through the [QGIS Plugin tutorial](https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/building_a_python_plugin.html) which I updated to QGis3 a little while ago.